# Android: onClick not sent by child of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, overloading

In an Android app, I want to handle clicks both on a background element and on foreground elements. In my test case, clicks on the foreground elements do not get sent.

I've taken a barebones Hello World project called Test, and altered it as follows.

In `activity_test.xml`, I have set ids for the layout and the `TextView`, and I have given them both `onClick` properties:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            ...
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:onClick="doStuff">

            <TextView
                    ...
                    android:id="@+id/hello_world"
                    android:textSize="52dp"
                    android:onClick="doStuff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

In the main `TestActivity` class, I have the following class:

```
    public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

                    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
                    doStuff(view);
                    Log.d("onCreate", "testing " + view.getId());
            }

            public void doStuff(TextView textView) {
                    Log.d("test", "text " + textView.getId() + " " + R.id.hello_world);
            }

            public void doStuff(View view) {
                    Log.d("test", "view " + view.getId() + " " + R.id.layout);
            }
    }
```

In the log window, after launching the app, I see the following:

> D/test﹕ text 2131165250 2131165250
>   D/onCreate﹕ testing 2131165250

This shows that the TestView version of the `doStuff` method is definitely triggered when a TestView parameter is sent.

However, if I now tap on the Hello World TextView, this is the line that is added to the log:

> D/test﹕ view 2131165249 2131165249

In other words, tapping the Hello World text has the same effect as tapping on the background itself. What do I need to do to get the TextView element to respond to its onClick setting?

Comment: Rename your methods .. ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but that had no effect.

Comment: Post the code with renamed methods, that you've tried. This is just too ambiguous.

Comment: I used the name "doStuff2" in 3 places: in the call made in onCreate, as the name of the method that receives a TextView argument, and as the onClick property for the TextView element in activity_test.xml. The results were identical to those shown above: the call made in onCreate() triggered doStuff2; tapping on the TextView or on the layout background triggered doStuff. Changing the name of the methods had no effect on the results.

Comment: I think the answer of @user3249477 will solve your problem, but overloading in this case is no good programming style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

The `TextView` is not clickable by default.

Comment: yeah, that is true. only layouts are clickable by default.

Comment: Setting android:clickable="true" does the trick! Thanks user3249477.

Answer (score 0):

hi can you use **setOnTouchListener**? then you can refer below given code.. it may work i think..
as per my knowledg, the problem is , whenever you touch textview, it will call **onTouchListener** for both textview and background.. sorry for my bad english

```
private int textViesTouchStatus = 0;//public variable

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textViesTouchStatus = 1;
            Log.d("touch_textview", "code that should be run on textview touch goes here");

            return false;
        }
    });

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay);
    layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (textViesTouchStatus == 1)
                textViesTouchStatus = 0;
            else
                Log.d("touch_background", "code that should be run on layout touch goes here");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: onTouchListener is out of question because there is no need to differentiate between the number of taps.